# "Can there be an incompleteness theorem of the second kind?"

Tags: logic

The question has also been asked in the Quora thread [Can there be an incompleteness theorem of the second kind?](https://qr.ae/pNKfwV) where the suggested theorem statement is:

*For any consistent FOL formal system semantically homologous with the concept of ***trichotomy***, there is a formally undecidable proposition.*

Comment: What does "semantically homologous with the concept of trichotomy" mean? For that matter, what do you mean by "of the second kind?" And looking at the quora question, it seems to actually only involve propositional logic, not anything relevant to Godelian incompleteness or first-order logic.

Comment: It means in this case the theory T would interpret the concept of trichotomy, just as, say, the FOL PA would interpret the concept "natural numbers".

Comment: It can be noted that Shoenfield's axiom N8 for his FOL PA is in form a variant of a trichotomy.

Comment: As for "of the second kind" meaning, the meta mathematical proof involved there is not a function of (nonlogical) arithmetic truths (as in Gödel's 1931 paper) but of FOL inference rules.

Comment: The full first-order theory of the structure $(\mathbb{Z};<)$ (for example) is complete and computable, and includes the trichotomy principle. That seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Would you like to forward this counterexample as a detailed answer to MSE or Quora?

Comment: (Fwiw, I have been blocked from making any answer in MSE).

Comment: I think this question would be much better if you explained what you want more clearly. The phrase "semantically homologous with the concept of trichotomy" is totally opaque - "semantically homologous" is just not a term within the subject, and using it just makes it harder to tell what you intend. I think the question would be better received if you replaced that terminology with e.g. what you wrote in your first comment to me.

Comment: Have added the Analysis section in the Quora-thread's answer.

Comment: Fwiw, have just added the two meta theorems in the _Analysis_ [here](https://qr.ae/pNKfwV):

_2nd Compactness theorem_ and
_Anti Completeness theorem - (a-Completeness)_.

Comment: Fyi., In section _Anti Completeness theorem - (a-Completeness)_, fixed an
overlook formulation of the dichotomy _A_ embedded with Shoenfield’s _N8_ axiom.
_A_ now is:

_A ↔ (N8 → (x=Sy)) xor (N8 → ~(x=Sy))_.

Comment: Fwiw, in a related matter (in conjunction with this question) I've posted a question and answer in the Quora thread https://qr.ae/pNMScc which in turns has the document link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a8CvDCwv3Q_x1sgRiQGfZHOZqr1tug6F/view?usp=sharing .

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, a counterexample to the conjecture would constitute a linear order $\mathcal{L}=(L;<)$ whose complete first-order theory is computable - or in more snappy jargon, a **decidable linear order**. These do exist, and in fact every naturally-occurring linear order that I'm aware of is decidable:

- Whenever $\mathcal{A}$ is interpretable in $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is decidable, so is $\mathcal{A}$. The structure $(\mathbb{N};+)$ is decidable, hence so is $(\mathbb{N};<)$ and $(\mathbb{Z};<)$ - the former being a reduct in the weak sense (the domains are the same and $<$ is definable in $(\mathbb{N};+)$), and the latter is a good exercise.
- In $(\mathbb{Q};<)$, if $\overline{a},\overline{b}$ are tuples with the same "basic shape" (that is, $a_i<a_j\leftrightarrow b_i<b_j$ for each $i,j$), then we have $(\mathbb{Q};<,\overline{a})\cong(\mathbb{Q};<,\overline{b})$ by a back-and-forth argument. This means that the full theory of a tuple is determined by its basic shape - which gives us quantifier elimination. Since the set of possible basic shapes of tuples is computable, this proves decidability. Larger countable dense linear orders (e.g. the algebraics) are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q};<)$ via back-and-forth, and so are also decidable. We get the same for $(\mathbb{R};<)$, either by using the same argument as for $\mathbb{Q}$ but with a bit more care re: back-and-forth-ness or by applying downwards Lowenheim-Skolem to show $(\mathbb{R};<)\equiv(\mathbb{Q};<)$.
- It's a bit harder to show, but every well-ordering is decidable. (One key simplifying step here is that every well-ordering is elementarily equivalent to one $<\omega^\omega$, so we can focus on a rather small set of examples.)

There are indeed linear orders whose theories are not computable, of course. For example, let $A=(a_i)_{i\in\omega}$ be any binary sequence and consider the linear order $$\mathcal{L}_A:=\mathbb{Z}+\underline{a_0+1}+\mathbb{Z}+\underline{a_1+1}+\mathbb{Z}+\underline{a_2+1}+...,$$ where $\underline{k}$ denotes the linear order with $k$ elements. We have $A\le_TTh(\mathcal{L}_A)$, since we can pick out $a_i$ in a definable way:think about counting limit points and pairs of adjacent limit points. So just pick some non-computable $A$. (This sort of coding of sets/sequences into linear orders via "separating blocks" - here, the $\mathbb{Z}$s - is a common technique in computable structure theory.) However, I don't know of any *natural* examples.

We can do a bit better:

> There is a consistent c.e. $\{<\}$-theory containing the linear order axioms which is **essentially incomplete** - that is, has no computable completions.

*Proof sketch*: Pick two computably-inseparable c.e. sets $X,Y$, and whip up a theory saying that the structure "looks like" $\mathcal{L}_A$ for some $A$ whose $n$th bit is $1$ if $n\in X$ and is $0$ if $n\in Y$. (It takes work to make this first-order. Note that any theory like this will have models quite different from $\mathcal{L}_A$ for any $A$; they will, however, have the form $\mathcal{L}_A+\mathcal{K}$ for some sequence $A$ and some linear order $\mathcal{K}$, and the complexity of the $\mathcal{L}_A$-part will be good enough for us.)

This leaves open the following:

> Is there a **finitely axiomatizable** $\{<\}$-theory containing the axioms of linear order which is essentially undecidable?

The shift from c.e. to finitely axiomatizable in the arithmetic context relies on the ability to code sequences in a particularly nice way, and we lack that here. So I suspect the answer is negative.

Comment: As mentioned in the Analysis section of the Quora's answer, if there's a counter example, then that implies either there exists contradiction in some laws of thought used in mathematical logic, or we have to forgo the hypotheses of the alleged counter example.

Comment: Are you saying then if one takes the essence of the logic - used to conclude your example is a counterexample - and applies it to (the Quora) Example 2 about John Conway's game of Life, one can conclude with 100% certainty that the cardinality of the set of glider-instances in all infinitely many generations is precisely, say, zero? It seems very much logically impossible to come to that conclusion, imho.